# Find maximum total weight over set of pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, maximize

I have a set of pairs of record IDs and for each pair a corresponding probability that these records actually belong to each other. Each pair is unique, but any given ID may be part of more than one pairing.

E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID_1': [1,1,1,2],
    'ID_2': [2,4,3,3],
    'w': [0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7]}
)

df
   ID_1  ID_2    w
0     1     2  0.5
1     1     4  0.5
2     1     3  0.6
3     2     3  0.7
```

(Note that not every ID has to be assigned to every other ID due to factors external to the problem. One could include those pairs and give them a probability of 0.)
How can I find the set of pairs where each ID is assigned to another ID not more than once (but an ID is allowed to not be assigned at all) such that the overall likelihood of pairs belonging to each other is maximized.

The dataframe I want to do this on is quite large, so setting this up as a maximum likelihood problem seems a bit over the top. I am not a computer scientist, but I thought there is probably an algorithm out there to solve this problem - optimally implemented in python.

The way I am doing it right now is in kind of a greedy way, which probably does not necessarily lead to the optimal solution. I start with the highest ranked pair. I put it into the final set and drop all pairs that involve any of the IDs from the set. I continue with the next lower ranked pair from the updated set in the same manner until there are no pairs left.

(Apologies if this is actually the wrong forum for this kind of question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to switch from using a column-row based model like you have with the data frames to using a **Graph** model.  There are several python libraries that can do this including NetworkX.  https://pypi.org/project/networkx/

The idea is each of your pairs becomes nodes in a graph, and then the edges are assigned the weights.  Once you have that data structure, you can take any given node and find the highest weight edge.  You can do all sorts of edge weight based path algorithms.

There is another python library:  https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy  which is built on networkx that will even be probability-aware.  It might have what you need even more closely.

For this sort of query a graph library is oodles more efficient than trying to do it with row-column data structures.

Comment: Thanks @rotten. It looks like what I am facing is a [Maximum Bipartite Matching problem](https://towardsdatascience.com/matching-of-bipartite-graphs-using-networkx-6d355b164567).

Comment: Actually, I have to correct myself. What I needed was the maximum weight matching of a general undirected graph. Anyway, pointing me to the Graph literature was the right hint. Thanks